# Trying to add a list of SP users of selected groups

Tags: sharepoint-designer, css, html5

I'm not exactly sure how to be more clear but I will do my best. I want all the members from whatever group is selected in the DropDownList3 to appear in my css list after they click button8. All SP Groups are populated in DropDownList3. Thanks for your help. I have posted all relevant code for this problem.

```
       public void Button8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //setting what group I want to display members from
        string group = DropDownList3.SelectedValue; 
        //sending that specified group to addMemberToList 
        addMemberToList(group);       
    }

    public void addMemberToList(string groupName)
    {
        SPSite site = new SPSite(Page.Request.Url.ToString());
        SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web;
        web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
        SPGroup spGroup = web.SiteGroups[groupName];


        foreach (SPUser member in spGroup.Users)
        {
      //Populating MyList for however many members are in whichever group they selected 
      // with the Name of the members
            myList.InnerHtml += "<li><a href='#'>" + member.Name + "</a></li>";
        }

    }
```

and on my .ascx page I have this

```
 <ol class="rectangle-list" runat="server" id="myList">                 
 </ol>
```

Lastly I have this as my css list

```
   <style type="text/css">
    ol{
counter-reset: li; /* Initiate a counter */
list-style: none; /* Remove default numbering */
*list-style: decimal; /* Keep using default numbering for IE6/7 */
font: 15px 'trebuchet MS', 'lucida sans';
padding: 0;
margin-bottom: 4em;
text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.5);
     }

     .rectangle-list a{
position: relative;
display: block;
padding: .4em .4em .4em .8em;
*padding: .4em;
margin: .5em 0 .5em 2.5em;
background: #ddd;
color: #444;
text-decoration: none;
transition: all .3s ease-out;   
    }

    .rectangle-list a:hover{
background: #eee;
    }   

  .rectangle-list a:before{
content: counter(li);
counter-increment: li;
position: absolute; 
left: -2.5em;
top: 50%;
margin-top: -1em;
background: #fa8072;
height: 2em;
width: 2em;
line-height: 2em;
text-align: center;
font-weight: bold;
       }

      .rectangle-list a:after{
position: absolute; 
content: '';
border: .5em solid transparent;
left: -1em;
top: 50%;
margin-top: -.5em;
transition: all .3s ease-out;               
      }


      .rectangle-list a:hover:after{
left: -.5em;
border-left-color: #fa8072;             
      } 
    </style>
```

Comment: for starters shouldn't the foreach be spuser user in spGroup and not groupName?

Comment: Updated but still not working: SPGroup spGroup = web.SiteGroups[groupName];

            foreach (SPUser member in spGroup.Users)

Comment: For some reason it is pulling the exact amount of groups I have in the list.

Comment: Can you post all your code... with more detail... I am having trouble figuring out what you actually mean...

Comment: I've edited now with as much detail as I think I can give at this point. Let me know if you still have questions.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by this: "For some reason it is pulling the exact amount of groups I have in the list"

Comment: BlueBird, thanks for your help. Realized I was just being very dumb. I forgot I was testing the code in page load event with the groups. I also forgot to add a button click event on the html side. sorry for wasting your time. Everything works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Wow.... I am new to the html side of things

I at first did not have the OnClick = "Button8_Click"... fixed everything. Here is the whole solution

```
      public void Button8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        myList.InnerHtml = "";
        string group = DropDownList3.SelectedValue;
        addMemberToList(group);       
    }

    public void addMemberToList(string groupName)
    {
        SPSite site = new SPSite(Page.Request.Url.ToString());
        SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web;
        web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
        SPGroup spGroup = web.SiteGroups[groupName];


        foreach (SPUser member in spGroup.Users)
        {

            myList.InnerHtml += "<li><a href='#'>" + member.Name + "</a></li>";
        }
```